# Overriding a prototype.js method

Tags: javascript, object, prototypejs

I'm attempting to override the Form.Element.disable() method in PrototypeJS so that it adds a custom class to disabled form elements.

I've added:

```
Form.Element.disable = function(element) {
element = $(element);
element.blur();
element.disabled = true;
element.addClassName("disabled");
return element;}
```

to the page after loading prototype.js - this works if called directly eg

```
Form.Element.disable("myInputBox");
```

But the original PrototypeJS method is used if I call

```
$("myInputBox").disable();
```

I know it's something to do with the "scope" in which I'm defining it - I'm effectively creating a new instance of the disable() method, but I have no idea how to shift the scope so that it replaces the original PrototypeJS version.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Form.Element.addMethods({
    disable: function(element) {
        // stuff here
    }
});
```

And if it doesn't work : http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/addMethods/

```
Element.addMethods(["input", "textarea", "select"], {
    disable: function(element) {
        // stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fabien - the first one resulted in an error (again a method I'd tried already), but the second tack did the trick.

I hadn't thought of simply adding the method to the specific elements on the page, instead of overriding the PrototypeJS method. Brilliant!

p.s. for those reading this later - you need an extra } at the end, so the code would read:

Element.addMethods(["input", "textarea", "select"], {
    disable: function(element) {
        // stuff here
    }
});

Answer (score -1):

```
Form.Element.prototype.disable = function(element) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Greg - nice try, but I already tried & failed with that one - generates a "Form.Element.prototype is undefined" error.